# Snowflake JSON with foreign language to tabular format dynamically

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I read through snowflake documentation and the web and found only one solution to my problem by https://stackoverflow.com/users/12756381/greg-pavlik which can be found here [Snowflake JSON to tabular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68397907/snowflake-json-to-tabular)

This doesn't work on data with Russian attribute names and attribute values. What modifications can be made for this to fit my case?
Here is an example:

```
    create or replace table target_json_table(
v variant
);

INSERT INTO target_json_table SELECT parse_json('{
  "at": {
    "cf": "NV"  
  },
  "pd": {
    "мо": "мо",
    "ä": "ä",
   "retailerName": "retailer",
    "productName":"product"
  }
}');

  call create_view_over_json('target_json_table', 'V', 'MY_VIEW');
```

ERROR: Encountered an error while creating the view. SQL compilation error: syntax error line 7 at position 7 unexpected 'ä:'. syntax error line 8 at position 7 unexpected 'мо'.

Comment: Please update the question providing sample column names and data that can reproduce the problem with the schema inference stored procedure you reference in that post.

Comment: Hi, I updated the question with a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in the original SQL used as a basis for the creation of the stored procedure. I have corrected that. You can get an update on the Github page. The changed section is here:

```
sql = 
`
SELECT DISTINCT '"' || array_to_string(split(f.path, '.'), '"."') || '"'                                         AS path_nAme,       -- This generates paths with levels enclosed by double quotes (ex: "path"."to"."element").  It also strips any bracket-enclosed array element references (like "[0]")
                DECODE (substr(typeof(f.value),1,1),'A','ARRAY','B','BOOLEAN','I','FLOAT','D','FLOAT','STRING')  AS attribute_type,  -- This generates column datatypes of ARRAY, BOOLEAN, FLOAT, and STRING only
                '"' || array_to_string(split(f.path, '.'), '.') || '"'                                           AS alias_name       -- This generates column aliases based on the path
FROM
        @~TABLE_NAME~@,
        LATERAL FLATTEN(@~COL_NAME~@, RECURSIVE=>true) f
WHERE   TYPEOF(f.value) != 'OBJECT'
        AND NOT contains(f.path, '[')         -- This prevents traversal down into arrays
limit   ${ROW_SAMPLE_SIZE}
`;
```

Previously this SQL simply replaced non-ASCII characters with underscores. The updated SQL will wrap key names in double quotes to create non-ASCII key names.

Be sure that's what you want it to do. Also, the keys are nested. I decided that the best way to handle that is to create column names in the view with dot notation, for example one column name is `pd.ä`. That will require wrapping the column name with double quotes, such as:

`select * from MY_VIEW where "pd.ä" = 'ä';`

Final note: The name of your stored procedure is `create_view_over_json`, however, in the Github project the name is `create_view_over_variant`. When you update, be sure to call the right procedure.